# Обход доменной политики. Флеш не работает на другом домене.

Tags: flash-player

Скопипастил флеш-плеер к себе на страничку, но плеер не работает ни на одном другом домене, кроме своего родного. Кто-нибудь знает, как обойти?
Помнится, обходил РНР защиту такого рода, присваивая глобальному `$_SERVER[host]`, или как там его, свой домен. Может, что-то подобное есть и у флеша?

Офигеть, только написал вопрос, а он уже в индексе гугла О_О:
Да и ещё в топ5:
[результат поиска](http://www.google.by/search?gcx=c&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C+%D0%B3%D0%B4%D0%B5+%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F+%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BE+flash#sclient=psy-ab&hl=ru&safe=off&source=hp&q=flash+%D0%BD%D0%B5+%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82+%D0%BD%D0%B0+%D0%B4%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%BC+%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B5&pbx=1&oq=flash+%D0%BD%D0%B5+%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82+%D0%BD%D0%B0+%D0%B4%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%BC+%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B5&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&gs_sm=e&gs_upl=22618l27656l0l27860l34l21l0l0l0l1l1244l16574l5-1.8.8l17l0&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.,cf.osb&fp=84d24d6baea54584&biw=1366&bih=667).

Comment: Гуглите "crossdomain.xml"

Comment: Просто создать этот файл в корне и прописать нужные домены?)

Comment: Хм, че-то я не все учел. Вообще есть неплохая вероятность, что да, сработает. Пробуйте) Другое дело, если он внутри где-то к домену привязан - там уже печальнее может быть дело.

Comment: Вроде бы как заработало, вот только плейлист не грузит :)) Спасибо +

Comment: Ну плейлист и не должно грузить т.к. у вас на сервере его нет ^.^

Comment: А как бы так узнать ссылки на видеофайлы чтобы всё работало? :)
Помогите в последний раз ^^